# What is the best way to store assets/content on a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, file-upload, server

I am working on a social app that will allow users to record voice notes.
The way I did it for testing is having some mp3 files in a folder inside the app for example ./audios/file.mp3
I would need to store the mp3 files from the users and other assets like images somewhere in the web and be able to get them with a url instead of having the files in the app files.
What options do I have for that ?

Answer (score 1):

The question here is, do you want to store your assets on a database as a blob or on a filesystem as files. [Here's a research paper which discusses this.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/to-blob-or-not-to-blob-large-object-storage-in-a-database-or-a-filesystem/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fapps%2Fpubs%2Fdefault.aspx%3Fid%3D64525)

Storing the assets as files is not a bad idea. What you can do is name your files using [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and store the UUID names in a database.

Then, to retrieve an asset, on the server side, first query the database to get the file name and retrieve the asset using the file name.

For node, the package [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) should be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you bootstrapped react app using create-react-app.

Store all the assets inside the `public` dir. You can create an `assets` folder inside the public dir, and store all assets inside of it.

Inside your app, the public dir can be pointed using the `PUBLIC_URL` env variable.

use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to retrieve the public dir and `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets` to point the assets dir.

I hope you understand.